# Moving multiple subfolder files to parent folder on Mojave?

Tags: finder, mojave, automator

I'm trying to move the files of multiple (100+) subfolders to the parent folder, but I don't want to do it manually for each. Is there something I could do to automate that?

I've tried solutions for older OS's and they don't seem to work, and I don't fully understand https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8385501

Thank you!

Comment: Michael, Welcome to Ask Different!. It would probably be a much better question if you'd included a representative sample of the _hierarchical folder structure_ you are working with, showing a before and after result. As currently written it is a bit ambiguous. Please take the time to improve your question by editing it adding the missing details. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Terminal run

```
cd PARENTFOLDER
mkdir -p $TMPDIR/move
mv */* $TMPDIR/move/
rmdir *
mv $TMPDIR/move/* .
rmdir $TMPDIR/move
```

Please note

- This will lead to data loss if files in different subfolders have the same name.
- `rmdir *` will fail if the subfolders aren't empty after the move (e.g. if they contain files/directories starting with a `.`)
- It works by first moving the files within the subfolders to a temporary location, then removing the subfolders themselves and then moving the files from them temporary location back to the parent. The moves are fast if they are on the same drive, they are very slow (and may fail due to lack of disk space) if the parent folder is on an external drive

---

For the extended version you've asked in the comments

> Is there an easy way to batch apply this for an entire folder? For example: Year (parent folder) > Month > Day 1, 2, etc. Where I can apply your function to every folder in Year, with the contents of Day 1 & 2 going into Month, but the content of Month don't go into Year?

```
_tmp=$(mktemp -d)
cd YEAR
for month in *; do
    [[ -d "$month" ]] || continue

    echo mv -- "$month"/*/* "$_tmp"/
    echo rmdir -- "$month"/*
    echo mv "$_tmp"/* "$month"/
done
rmdir "$_tmp"
```

Remove the `echo`s if the output of the dry run looks ok.

Comment: Thanks, this works! Is there an easy way to batch apply this for an entire folder? For example:

Year (parent folder) > Month > Day 1, 2, etc.

Where I can apply your function to every folder in Year, with the contents of Day 1 & 2 going into Month, but the content of Month don't go into Year?

Comment: @Michael Sure. The tricky thing here is that the more rules you add the more difficult it gets to write a script without having access to the system in question.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood it correctly, so I entered "_tmp=$(mktemp -d)", pressed enter, entered "cd 2019", pressed enter, then copy/pasted the rest while removing the echo's, pressed enter?

When I do that, it runs through the subfolder and says "Not a directory", and "rename /var/folders/.../tmp.... to Month: No such file or directory". Not sure what's going on? Would adding sudo somewhere help?

Comment: @michael sudo will not help! As I said it‘s difficult to get such things right without details about the actual folder structure.  And the idea of the echos was to keep them in first to see if it works correctly, without already changing anything. I‘ll try to update later

Comment: @michael Just tested with an empty directory structure matching your description, seems to work. So we may miss part of the details here. As this is hard to figure out in the comments, please ask a new question for this and include subsets of the content of the relevant directories.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by nohillside, you can use Spotlight to search for the files within the parent folder.

So, for instance, if you have hundreds of text files spread across folders within one single parent folder, you can use Finder’s search function to look for text files of any name. Just type in the search box “text” — or any other format, such as “docx,” or name of application, such as “word” — and a drop-down list should appear. Choose your desired format and Finder will search the current directory for any file corresponding to that format.

Then, with the files organized in the search window, you can select all and move them to another folder of your choosing.

This method, while a bit tedious, can also be used for files of different formats, provided that you use Finder to search for each format (such as .txt or .docx), select and move all the results, and then search again for the remaining file formats within the parent folder.

I hope this helps.

EDIT: I don’t know how this would affect files that have the same name, so it might be a good idea to test on a few files before proceeding.

Answer (score -1):

> I'm trying to move the files of multiple (100+) subfolders to the parent folder, but I don't want to do it manually for each. Is there something I could do to automate that?

Here is one way to handle it...

1. Open **Terminal**.
2. Change *directory* to the *parent directory* containing the *sub directories*, e.g.:

   ```
    cd /path/to/parent
   ```
3. Use the following *command* to move all *files* in the *sub directories* to the *parent directory*, the one the `cd` *command* was set to in the previous step:

   ```
    find . -type f -name '*' -exec mv -n '{}' . \;
   ```

   - Note that this *command* just moves ***files***, not *folders* or *application bundles*, and **does not** overwrite *files* of the same *name* already in the *parent directory*.
4. To remove the empty *sub directories*, use the following *command*:

   ```
    find . -type d -name '*' -exec rm -d '{}' \;
   ```

   - Note that any *sub directories* not deleted contains *files* of the same *name* already in the *parent directory*, or an *application bundle* if any exist. You can decide how to handle it after you see what's left. If just a few *files* didn't get moved maybe just do the few *files* manually.

**NOTE:** Always insure you have proper backups before running *commands* in **Terminal** and the *commands* as typed will produce the wanted behavior!

Comment: To whomever downvoted... As this answer actually does move _files_ from the _sub directories_ to the _parent directory_ from which it's executed and is what I believe the OP asked for, it would certainly be more productive if you'd state a legitimate reason for the downvote so the answer can be improved if needed.